# Is there a way to simplify this expression further?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose multivariate function $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln \left( 1+e^{\,-c_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^n {d_{ij}} x_j} \right)$, where $c_i$ is either $1$ or $-1$ and $d_{ij}$ is arbitrary real number.

---

I'd like to simplify the gradient of $f(X)$ for the purpose of gradient-based optimization, specifically, I attempt to further simplify $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{e^{\,-c_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^n d_{ij} x_j} (-c_id_{ik})} {1+e^{\,-c_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^n d_{ij} x_j }}$.

---

Of course, if it's possible to simplify in any matrix way, I would be glad to know since many science softwares support matrix algebra. But is it possible to further simplify the gradient?

Answer (score 1):

Use a series of variable substitutions to build up to the function 
$$\eqalign{
  y &= Ax &\ \ \  dy = A\,dx \cr
  z &= -c\circ y &\ \ \  dz = -c\circ dy \cr
  e &= \exp(z) &\ \ \ de = e\circ dz \cr
  h &= 1+e &\ \ \ dh = de \cr
  g &= \log(h) &\ \ \  dg = \frac{dh}{h} \cr
  f &= 1:g &\ \ \ df = 1:dg \cr
}$$
where the {Hadamard, Frobenius} products have been denote by the symbols {$\,\circ, :\,$} respectively.

Also note the use of $A_{ij}=d_{ij}$ so as to avoid confusion with derivatives or differentials.

Continuing the expansion of that last differential
$$\eqalign{
 df &= 1:dg \cr
    &= 1:\frac{dh}{h} \cr
    &= 1:\frac{e\circ dz}{h} \cr
    &= 1:\frac{(1-h)\circ c\circ dy}{h} \cr
    &= (h^{-1}-1)\circ c:dy \cr
    &= (H^{-1}-I)\,c:A\,dx \cr
    &= A^T(H^{-1}-I)\,c:dx \cr\cr
}$$
where $H={\rm Diag}(h)$.

So the gradient could be written as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= A^T(H^{-1}-I)\,c \cr
}$$